# Get text from current editing cell in a Datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I would like to read the text of the current cell being edited by the user. I 'd like to filter a listbox based on what the user is typing on a cell in a datagrid control. I thought in implementing it on a KeyDown event of the datagrid, but I can't find a way to read the value of the cell. I would like do read the value as the user type in, not the final edited value after the user press Enter. Any ideas?

Comment: "I would like do read the value as the user type in, not the final edited value after the user press Enter." Why would you want to do that? You only get that if you constantly .endEdit() and then try to read as they type, but that seems like you'd rather have a text box at that point.

Comment: You should allow them to type what ever they want to and if you have some specific well defined business filter rules in regards to what can be considered a valid edit, then from there do some validation checking before allowing the row to be updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you . Take a [look](http://www.dhirajranka.com/2012/01/capture-datagridview-cells-keypress-event/)

```
void dgvDemo_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
TextBox txt = e.Control as TextBox;
if (txt != null)
 {
    txt.KeyPress += new
   KeyPressEventHandler(txt_KeyPress);
 }
}

void txt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
 MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString());
}
```

This sample i done in WPF.

```
  <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyName}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyName}" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Codebehind

```
 private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

pls check ,this might help you

Comment: That would be exactly it, but this is for WinForms, I'm using WPF.

Comment: @RBasniak are u following mvvm pattern